# Selecting boundaries or start & end positions of a string angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a string in my webpage (developed using MEAN) from which I select a substring using mouse drag(`ng-mouseup`). Now I want to get those indices (start position and ending position/length of substring)

I know this can be achieved with `indexOf` but this returns only the first match.

But there is possibility that the string can contain words that are repetitive. In this case `indexOf` doesn't serve my purpose.

Regards,
Kiriti

Comment: It is always better to include some code with the question.

Comment: @Mamun it's a direct question, how to get the boundaries of a substring that is selected using ng-mouseup

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily I got an answers while surfing for the solution, hope it might help some one else who is looking for it.

Also please let me know whether I can use this or it will cause any problem or caution needs to be taken care while using this solution.

```
substring = window.getSelection().toString();
startingPosition = window.getSelection().anchorOffset;
lenght = window.getSelection().focusOffset - startingPosition
```